# How to extract important features after k-fold cross validation, with or without a pipeline?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want to build a classifier that uses cross validation, and then extract the important features (/coefficients) from each fold so I can look at their stability. At the moment I am using cross_validate and a pipeline. I want to use a pipeline so that I can do feature selection and standardization within each fold. I'm stuck on how to extract the features from each fold. I have a different option to using a pipeline below, if that is the problem.

This is my code so far (I want to try `SVM` and logistic regression). I've included a small df as example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'length': [5, 8, 0.2, 10, 25, 3.2], 
                   'width': [60, 102, 80.5, 30, 52, 81],
                   'group': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]})

array = df.values
y = array[:,2]
X = array[:,0:2]

select = SelectKBest(mutual_info_classif, k=2)
scl = StandardScaler()
svm = SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True, random_state=42)
logr = LogisticRegression(random_state=42)

pipeline = Pipeline([('select', select), ('scale', scl), ('svm', svm)])

split = KFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

output = cross_validate(pipeline, X, y, cv=split, 
                scoring = ('accuracy', 'f1', 'roc_auc'),
                return_estimator = True,
                return_train_score= True)
```

I thought I could do something like:

```
pipeline.named_steps['svm'].coef_
```

but I get error message:

```
AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute 'dual_coef_'
```

If it's not possible to do this using a pipeline, could I do it using 'by hand' cross validation? e.g:

```
for train_index, test_index in kfold.split(X, y):

        kfoldtx = [X[i] for i in train_index]
        kfoldty = [y[i] for i in train_index]
```

But I'm not sure what to do next! Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `output` of `cross_validate` to get the parameters of the fitted model. The reason is that `cross_validate` would clone the pipeline. Hence you would not find given `pipeline` variable be fitted after been fed to `cross_validate`.

`output` is dictionary, which has `estimator` as one of the keys, whose value is a `k_fold` number of fitted `pipeline` objects.

From [**Documentation**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html):

> **return_estimator :** boolean, default False
>
> Whether to return the estimators fitted on each split.

Try this!

```
>>> fitted_svc = output['estimator'][0].named_steps['svm'] # choosing the first fold comb
>>> fitted_svc.coef_

array([[1.05826838, 0.41630046]])
```

Comment: It works! Amazing, thank you, have been struggling ages with that. Can I just check with you that I am using the pipeline correctly - I don't need to call `.fit` anywhere, as this is achieved using `cross_validate`? Also could you point me in the right direction to map the coeficient array to the original df column headers? When I try on my larger dataset I get `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 5), indices imply (50, 302)`.

Comment: Yes, you dont have to fit again, each model had been already fitted. Note: you would get `k_fold` number of models. Your second part of question is not clear! can you added more details about it in your question?

Comment: May be of use for you: the shape of `coef_` would be `[n_class * (n_class-1) / 2, n_features]`. Read more in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)

Comment: OK great, I thought that but wanted to check :). Second part: because I'm using `SelectKbest`, e.g. selecting top 5 features, I have an array of 5 coefficients per fold. How do I know which feature names they correspond to, which are the column headers in my original df? I hope I've explained myself better!

Comment: `output['estimator'][0]['select'].get_support()` this will give you the list of variables selected.

Comment: Brilliant, so then I just use a mask to convert them to a df. Thank you so much!